# javascript __doPostBack doesn't seem to work for me

Tags: asp.net, javascript, postback

I use yui datatable in my asp.net application... I have a link button in one of my columns and it works fine but doesn't do a postback of a hidden button...

```
 myDataTable.subscribe("linkClickEvent", function(oArgs) {
            javascript: __doPostBack('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1', '');
            YAHOO.util.Event.stopEvent(oArgs.event);
        });
```

and in my page

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button"
   style="display:none;" />

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    DownloadFile(Hfhref.Value, true);
 }
```

I used break point but it doesn't seem to get the `__dopostback`.. Any suggestion...

Comment: @Panidiya Why you have type on front javascript: ?

Comment: @Aristos releasing that too didnt work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did this and it worked,

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1").click();
```

just call `click()` my button it worked...

I want to know whether it works in all browsers...

Comment: Oddly enough, this worked for me as well. I say "oddly" because I can't get __doPostBack to work for a ASP.NET LinkButton that has ClientIDMode set to static.

Answer (score 3):

add unique id on __doPostBackMethod from Button.

Comment: How did I not see that? The first parameter of __doPostBack should be the Control's UniqueId, not the ClientId. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ASP.Net 4.0 framework, add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your control declaration and you can call `__doPostBack('Button1','');` directly.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button"
   style="display:none;" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

The ClientIDMode attribute is new to 4.0 and allows you the option of having a known unique id for controls. Calling postback for the control will run whatever postback method is defined in the control's OnClick attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In your markup, make sure to properly case the OnClick handler.

```
onclick="Button1_Click"
```

should be

```
OnClick="Button1_Click"
```

The way you have written it, onclick will be interpreted as an attribute of the control and `onclick="Button1_Click"` will be rendered to the browser, instead of being handled on the server side.